# User commands parser

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-parser

Is there any python module which is a parser for user input data and executes user commands and processes Python syntax? For example:

```
user>for i in range(3):
...    doSomething()
```

Above line will execute doSomething() method 3 times. I know there are many packages with parsers but I haven't seen any with possibility to execute Python syntax.

Comment: Objective not clear. please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what exactly you're looking for. It sounds like you're asking for a Python shell, in which case you should run `python` at the command prompt. On the other hand, if you're looking for a command line argument parsing library, try `argparse` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).